# How do I transfer files over ssh and also change their permission on the remote server without having to log in twice

Tags: shell, ssh, scp, chmod

```
guy@home~% scp file.* guy@server.server.com:/users/guy/public_html/kool-stuff/
```

Ok so this transfers some files.  Then I usually have to login in another terminal and do this in order to make them visible on the web (perhaps because of the settings on the server? I don't know.)

```
guy@server~$ cd ~/public_html/kool-stuff
guy@server~$ chmod 755 ./file.*
```

Can I do both in a single command on my local machine?

Answer (score 2):

[`scp`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/scp.1) has a `-p` option:

```
 -p      Preserves modification times, access times, and modes from the
         original file.
```

So set your permissions locally and then do the `scp`.

Or, you can use `tar`:

```
tar -zc file.* | ssh guy@... 'tar -zx -C ~/public_html/kool-stuff; chmod 755 ~/public_html/kool-stuff/file.*'
```

In either case, I doubt *execute* permissions are necessary if they are files.